# Importing angular component to be available in all modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

I've recently started playing with angular 2 and my experience so far is awesome. I have some good experience with `ng1` and `React` as well. So, this is more of a general question and a confusion as well. I am pretty sure this would help out a lot of other people as well as I haven't really found any direct answer to this.

So let's say I have this `module` `protected.module.ts` where I have some components registered. So, in order to use primitive directives `ngFor, ngIf` I would have to import `CommonModule` to the the specific module but along with that I would have to import this to the main entry module i.e. `app.module.ts`.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule  } from '@angular/common';
import { AlertModule  } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProtectedModule } from './protected/protected.module';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/components/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    LayoutModule,
    ProtectedModule,
    UsersModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**protected.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule  } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProtectedRoutingModule } from './protected-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ProtectedRoutingModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent]
})
export class ProtectedModule { }
```

So, the confusion I had was if there was a way to just import some module globally in `app.module` if we wanted to use that module across all the modules that we would eventually have? With this way, it seems like a overhaul to me that we need to import it to different places. Or am I missing some point here completely?

Thank you in advance and I really hope this would be beneficial for me and to other folks as well.

Comment: First thing in `app.module.ts`, you dont need to import `CommonModule` so you can remove it. Other thing is I dont understand your question completely. Please  search for `sharedModule` in agular.io maybe that can help you...

Comment: @micronyks If I remove `CommonModule` from `app.module.ts` it throws an error.

Comment: @micronyks Let say I have `moduleA` and `moduleB`, and if I wanted to use some module in both, is there a possibility to add it just in `app.module.ts` and use it in both `moduleA` and `moduleB` or would I have to import it individually in `moduleA` and `moduleB`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'd be best served with a  [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#sharedmodule)

Your other `modules` (typically `feature modules` in my experience) can all import this `shared module`.
As described in the documentation, you can reduce the repeated import statements by having the `SharedModule` re-export common dependencies e.g. `CommonModule`, `FormsModule`

As an example, you can have a shared module just re-export `BrowserModule`, `FormsModule` and `HttpModule` like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    exports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And then in your other modules, instead of importing those same modules, just import the `SharedModule` like below. Every module that imports the `SharedModule` will be able to use everything **exported** from the `SharedModule` without explicitly importing it again.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from './path_to_shared_module/shared.module';
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule, ...],
    ...
})
export class OtherModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this.