# "'wizard' is not a known element" error, even when importing that component

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2.4 and am getting the following error in my browser console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'wizard' is not a
>   known element:
>   1. If 'wizard' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'wizard' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   ("oduction-tour" class="continue-tour" data-toggle="modal">Continue
>   Tour
>           
>           [ERROR ->]
>
> "): SellingComponent@79:8 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

This is the type of error I usually get if I forget to import a component in my app.module file, but I didn't forget this time.

Here is my **app.module.ts** file:

```
import { WizardComponent } from './wizard.component';
import { WizardService }   from './wizard.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...        
        SellingModule,
        GrowingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
        WizardComponent,
    ],
    providers: [        
        ...
        WizardService        
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**growing.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        GrowingComponent,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class GrowingModule { }
```

**selling.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: [
        SellingComponent,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class SellingModule { }
```

**growing.component.html**

```
<wizard></wizard>
```

**selling.component.html**

```
<wizard></wizard>
```

**wizard.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'wizard',
    templateUrl: 'wizard.component.html',
})
```

As you can see, I am trying to use `<wizard></wizard>` in two different components. I tried importing my WizardComponent in both my GrowingModule and SellingModule instead of my AppModule, but got a different error for importing it twice, so I thought I had to just import it once in my AppModule. If I only put `<wizard></wizard>` in growing.component.html and then only import WizardComponent in GrowingModule, it works. What do I have to do to be able to use `<wizard></wizard>` in both components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to re-use a common component in several feature modules (i.e.  Selling and Growing modules), you'd be better off defining those components in a shared module rather than in the `AppModule`.

Then you can import the `SharedModule` where required in your feature modules.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081915/importing-angular-component-to-be-available-in-all-modules/42082278#42082278) answer, and the Angular [shared module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module) documentation.