TranslatePipe ngx-translate globally
I'm using angular in setup which uses app.config and ngx-translate library. I created a TranslationModule file that initializes my language throughout my application but to do the translate in each component I need to import TranslatePipe. I would like to import TranslatePipe globally so I don't need to import it into each component.
this is translation.module.ts
const httpLoaderFactory: (http: HttpClient) => TranslateHttpLoader = (http: HttpClient) =>
      new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './i18n/', '.json');
    export function initializeLanguage(translate: TranslateService): () => Promise<void> {
      return async () => {
        translate.addLangs(['it', 'en']);
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        await lastValueFrom(translate.use(translate.getBrowserLang() || "en"));
      };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeLanguage,
      deps: [TranslateService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class  TranslationModule { }

this is app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(TranslationModule)
  ]
};

this is app.component.ts (correct)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, TranslatePipe],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
}

this is app.component.ts (wrong)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
}

this is app.component.html
<div>
  <h1>{{ 'app.hello' | translate }}</h1>
</div>


pipe cannot be provided globally unless you use modules or submodules, standalone components require the pipe to be imported

@NarenMurali I don't need my component to be standalone, how can I resolve this by perhaps setting standalone false

You cannot import the pipe by itself, you must import the TranslateModule.
If you want to avoid having to import the TranslateModule for every component, you can import it into a shared module, and then import the shared module in your components. Surely there are other modules that you will also import for every component, so this at least cuts down on the repetition.
Checkout this existing answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082278/1892543
